# SEARCH SAME ITEM IN EXCEL WITH DIFFERENT QUANTITY USING VBA

Tags: excel, search, vba

I have two excel sheets.

First sheet contain `item code`, `item name` and its `quantity` (`DATA` sheet). Quantity is different in each entry.

[image: DATA SHEET]

On the second sheet I have one text box and search button.

[image: DATA SHEET]

When I enter in `textbox1` some item code and hit search I need all data from first sheet that is correspondent to that code to be shown on `search sheet` displaying details in `c8,c9,c10` respectively.

Comment: Please, elaborate, what yo have and what exactly you want to achive? Also it would be nice to see what have you tried.

Comment: can u give me your email id to send my excel sheet

Comment: Thanks, this screenshots are more than enough to understand your question.

Comment: if u have excel 2010 and above, this is easily achievable using one pivot table and two slicer

Answer (score 0):

I create a similar Excel file. My `SEARCH SHEET` looks like this:

[image]

The VBA code for button, with explanation:

```
Sub Button_Click()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SearchSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Set the variables
    Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
    Set SearchSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SEARCH SHEET")

    'Clear content of search sheet
    SearchSheet.Cells.Range(SearchSheet.Cells(2, 1), SearchSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3)).ClearContents

    'I went from the cell row2/column1 and go down until the last non empty cell
    Set SearchRange = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(2, 1), DataSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    i = 1

    For Each rCell In SearchRange 'loop through each cell in the range

        'Check if the cell is equal to value of TextBox1
        If rCell.Text = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.Text Then
            i = i + 1   'Row number +1 everytime when occurance is found
            SearchSheet.Cells(i, 1) = rCell.Offset(0, 0) 'ITEM CODE
            SearchSheet.Cells(i, 2) = rCell.Offset(0, 1) 'ITEM NAME
            SearchSheet.Cells(i, 3) = rCell.Offset(0, 2) 'QUANTITY
        End If

    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you think an advanced search will be quicker than looping?

Comment: @ScottCraner What do you mean by advanced search? I am not so much familiar with Excel VBA and it would be nice if you give some pointers.

Comment: Sorry meant advanced filter.

Comment: see here for a nice tutorial: http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/

Comment: @ScottCraner Great! Thanks! Sure it must be quicker.

Comment: When I enter any alphabet or (number more than 6) its showing debug

Comment: It only checks `item code` field, as was mentioned in your question. There is `CInt` function that converts input and values from first column in integer. What does it mean *more than 6*? It is length? If so integer in excel VBA having this interval `-32,768 to 32,767` [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8EBB0E94-2D43-4975-BB13-87AC8D1A2202). You can change `CInt` to `CLng`

Comment: with your help I changed cing to clng and the number problem get solved but when my item code start with A125 and B125.... its not working (debug)

Comment: I get you :) Changed answer, give it a try. I used `Text` instead of `Value`.

Comment: My pleasure! If the answer was helpful, please, accept/upvote it.